# How to add the same string multiple times at the end of a CSV file?

Tags: string, ubuntu, awk, terminal, cat

I want to add the string "x,0" 430 times as new lines in an existing CSV document called "file.csv".

Is there a way to do this using the Ubuntu terminal?

Thank you for responses!

X

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'x,0\n%.0s' {1..430} >> file.csv
```

or

```
 yes "x,0" |  head -n 430  >> file.csv
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times

Comment: Darn, I was just about to post that `printf`! Other non-loop solutions would be `seq 430 | sed 's/.*/x,0/'` or `seq 430 | awk '{print "x,0"}'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=430;i++) print "x,0"}' >> file.csv
```